# Update through associations Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to modify 2 fields of my "Schedule" table but I can not. I have errors that appears. I do not understand:

I have multiples fields in this table, but I just want to change the start date, and the end date

This is the method:

```
exports.updateWorkingDates = (req, res) => {
Coach.find({
    where: {
        id: req.params.coachId
    },
    include: [{
        model: Schedule,
        attributes: ['start_date', 'end_date']
    }]
}).then(coach => {
    const updatedSchedule = {
        start_date: req.body.start_date,
        end_date: req.body.end_date ? req.body.end_date : null
    }
    coach.setSchedule(updatedSchedule).then(() => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Modified."
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    })
}
```

The error:

```
Error: Invalid value { start_date: '2018-07-07' }
```

The model:

```
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Schedule = sequelize.define('Schedule', {
    start_date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    end_date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    monday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    tuesday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    wednesday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    thursday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    friday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    saturday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    sunday: DataTypes.STRING(24)
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  Schedule.associate = function (models) {
    Schedule.belongsTo(models.Coach, {
      foreignKey: 'fk_id_coach'
    })
  };
  return Schedule;
};
```

Thank's :)

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to bring the date to a specific format

Should be to use moment.js
https://momentjs.com/

Example:

```
const updatedSchedule = {
    start_date: moment(req.body.start_date),
    end_date: req.body.end_date ? moment(req.body.end_date) : null
}
```

Moment formats:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // September 4th 2018, 5:20:54 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Tuesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Sep 4th 18
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2018 escaped 2018
moment().format();                          // 2018-09-04T17:20:54+03:00
```

Good luck!

Comment: I added moment, but I still have the same mistake: /

Comment: Yep, ` start_date: moment(req.body.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`, but still same error : `Error: Invalid value { start_date: '2018-07-07', end_date: '2018-07-30' }
    at Object.escape`

Comment: Are you using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I created this and it works:

```
Schedule.update({
    start_date: req.body.start_date,
    end_date: req.body.end_date ? req.body.end_date : null,
}, {
    where: {
        fk_id_coach: req.params.coachId
    }
}).then(() => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Dates modifiées."
    })
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({
        error: err
    })
})
```